# BerkeleyDB version incompatible with BDB/HDB backends

Tags: linux, kerberos, openldap

I am using Ubuntu 14.4 LTS.
I am trying to install openldap 2.4.42.
I have succesfully installed the pre-requisite components : 
Cyrus-sasl.2.1.24, krb5-1.13.2,openssl-0.9.8 and db-6.1.26

I was previously getting the following error when I was running ./configure :
configure: error: BDB/HDB: BerkeleyDB not available

I then ran the following command :

env CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.6.1/include -I/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl" ./configure --with-tls --enable-slurpd --enable-crypt --enable-syslog --sysconfdir=/etc

Yet now I am getting :
configure: error: BerkeleyDB version incompatible with BDB/HDB backends

I am quite new and did a bit of research but I honestly don't understand the command I used nor what the error is actually pointing to.

Any assistance is welcome.

Comment: Consider using MDB instead of BDB. MDB is modern, fast and more reliable than BDB. Also, MDB comes with OpenLDAP distr, so you don't need to install it separately and worry about versions.

Answer (score 3):

openldap-2.4.4 configure text file line 20387:

```
require 4.4 or later, but less than 6.0.20
```